# failed to build android 4.4 on mac 10.9

Tags: android, macos

I meet a question on Mac OS 10.9 with JDK1.6 and Xcode 5.1, my configures are the same as android official website, but some people did build successfully. I have tried to change different  gcc version, like replacing by gcc in homebrew or macports, but it did not work. Have someone build successfully? Could you help me check this error?
Thanks

```
prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libRSDriver_intermediates/driver/rsdMesh.o: file is empty

out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libRSDriver_intermediates/driver/rsdCore.o:frameworks/rs/driver/rsdCore.cpp:function FunctionTable: error: undefined reference to 'rsdMeshInit(android::renderscript::Context const*, android::renderscript::Mesh const*)'

out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libRSDriver_intermediates/driver/rsdCore.o:frameworks/rs/driver/rsdCore.cpp:function FunctionTable: error: undefined reference to 'rsdMeshDraw(android::renderscript::Context const*, android::renderscript::Mesh const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'

out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libRSDriver_intermediates/driver/rsdCore.o:frameworks/rs/driver/rsdCore.cpp:function FunctionTable: error: undefined reference to 'rsdMeshDestroy(android::renderscript::Context const*, android::renderscript::Mesh const*)'

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libRSDriver_intermediates/LINKED/libRSDriver.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it!
I preciously compiled it on Ubuntu 12.04, and copied the driver directory to the out directory on mac, and it finally succeeded!